# How to rewrite url name from webconfig

Tags: c#, url

i want to rewrite url name from WebConfig file..I have old url like this

http://www.exmaple.com/'blogdetails'/some name/10082

Now my url is being changed to 
http://www.exmaple.com/blog/details/some name/10082.
blogdetails is being chnaged to blog/Details..
Actually i waana redirect the url page when url will find a keyword 'blogdetails'..It will redirect to http://exmaple.com/blog   page..i want to do this from web config file..

example like if i enter the old url like http://www.exmaple.com/'blogdetails'/somename/10082

this link contain "blogdetails" it will redirect to http://www.exmaple.com/blog. 
i already got some code from internet some thing like..cause new link is being changed to blog/details..i dont wanna redirect to new link i just wanna redirect to this link something like this:- http://www.exmaple.com/blog

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="SpecificRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^blogdetails$" />

                <action type="Rewrite" url="blog" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

how to do this???can anyone help me please?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting blogdetails to always be at the root, I think this might work:

```
^blogdetails.*$
```

Comment: I just added the dollar sign at the end sorry. I think that will do it.

Comment: ok i am trying..Actually i am searching the solution thats why i am replying late

Comment: actually when i write www.example.com/blogdetails it worrking fine with my code <match url="^blogdetails$" /> but when i add some extra after blogdetails it is not working like   http://www.exmaple.com/'blogdetails'/somename/10082 it is not working with my code

Comment: still not working..can i send my real url link hope you will understand

Comment: Why is blogdetails in single quotes? Is this maybe why it's breaking?

Comment: <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="SpecificRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                
                <match url="^blogdetails.*$" />
             
                
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/blog" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>

Comment: it is working now but css path is changing i dont know why

Comment: What do you mean? Give me a quick example, we might be able to figure it out.

Comment: After redirecting,the page is not getting the css path so design is breaking..I checked with other pages also..There is a no problem for redirecting but dont know why css is not getting

Comment: Make sure the path to the CSS is absolute. You must be using a relative path, something like ../../css/file.css. Instead, use the absolute path: /css/file.css.

Answer (score 0):

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="SpecificRewrite" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=“^en/blogdetails$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url=“blog” />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Try this one.This should work.

Comment: it my suggestion, then check your path which you are passing. And please update me  the error you are getting in console browser.